# How do I get Selenium to switch to a different active tab on the page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Python and in need of some help.

I am using Python Selenium - Chrome to extract data, and need my Python script to be able to toggle between the options that appear as tabs on the [webpage](https://main.sci.gov.in/case-status).

Tried multiple ways to get the browser to identify and click the tab I need to switch to, but its just not happening and shows up an error for the field I want to populate on that tab:

```
        <div id="tabbed-nav">            
            <ul>
                <li><a>Diary Number</a></li>
                <li><a>Case Number</a></li>
                <li><a>Party Name</a></li>
                <li><a>AOR</a></li>
                <li><a>Court / Tribunal</a></li>
```

Filing Defects-->

```
                <li><a>Free Text</a></li>
            </ul>          
            <div>
```

Here are the two ways I tried to get the script to click on the tab, which for some reason is not working

```
Object.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabbed-nav']/ul[1]/li[3]").click()

Object.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='tabbed-nav']/ul/li/a[.="Party Name"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Before we analyze your two attempts, let me paste the current (simplified) DOM tree of the page in question for the future reference:

```html
<div id="tabbed-nav">
   <ul class="z-tabs-nav z-tabs-mobile">
      <li><a><span class="z-title">Diary Number</span><span class="z-arrow"></span></a></li>
   </ul>
   <i class="z-dropdown-arrow"></i>
   <ul class="z-tabs-nav z-tabs-desktop">
      <li class="z-tab z-first z-active" data-link="tab1"><a class="z-link">Diary Number</a></li>
      <li class="z-tab" data-link="tab2"><a class="z-link">Case Number</a></li>
      <li class="z-tab" data-link="tab3"><a class="z-link">Party Name</a></li>
      <li class="z-tab" data-link="tab4"><a class="z-link">AOR</a></li>
      <li class="z-tab" data-link="tab5"><a class="z-link">Court / Tribunal</a></li>
      <li class="z-tab z-last" data-link="tab6"><a class="z-link">Free Text</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="z-container">
      <!-- skipped -->
   </div>
</div>
```

And now the analysis of your two attempts:

**Attempt no 1**

```py
Object.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tabbed-nav']/ul[1]/li[3]").click()
```

There are two `ul` tags in your `//*[@id='tabbed-nav']` - the first one for mobile version of the page and the second one for the desktop version of the page.
You are choosing the first one (`/ul[1]`) which only contains one `<li>` tag while you are asking for the 3rd one. That's why no element is found.

**Attempt no 2**

```py
Object.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='tabbed-nav']/ul/li/a[.="Party Name"]').click()
```

This is almost correct! There is just a mess in `"` and `'`. The correct string with xpath follows:

```py
Object.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='tabbed-nav']/ul/li/a[.='Party Name']").click()
```

This works well for the current DOM structure.

Comment: The second one worked, appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @Kunal You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle